# Get pre-1990 prints (or masters) of movies? What happens to them?

Tags: distribution

Is it possible to rent original prints (or masters) of pre-1990 movies?

What happens to the original release prints of old movies? Do they just get destroyed?

In the old days you could rent 16mm prints of movies, but that practice seems to have died out in the 1970s, so 16mm prints of 1970s and 1980s movies do not seem to exist.